# Prove that $f$ is differentiable on $\Bbb R$ and find the derivative.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

$$f(x) = g(x)|g(x)|$$.

I know that to prove that a function is differentiable, I need to prove that $$\lim_{x \to c} \frac {f(x) - f(c)}{x-c}.$$

And then to prove that the function is differentiable on $\Bbb R$, I should prove that f'(c) exists for all c in R. I know how to do these proofs if g(x) is actually defined, but since it is not, I am stuck on how to proceed.

Comment: what about differentiability of $g$ itself, is it differentiable

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to assume $g$ is differentiable at $c$. Try to prove that $w(x) = x|x|$ is differentiable. Then use the chain rule.